# Help needed after Wubi install

Tags: wubi

The installation went well as shown on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows - but when booted through 'ubuntu' option, a screen shows a grub> prompt. What to do next??

Comment: Run `chkdsk /r` and then check if the `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` is there - or else refer to this: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html

Comment: PS I am assuming that you booted into Ubuntu successfully before this problem happened. Please edit your answer to confirm either way (more details are better).

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This was **answered in a comment** (this answer might not be sufficient for everyone, but it will likely solve the problem for many people, and provide a source of diagnostic information for even more).</sup>

> Run `chkdsk /r` and then check if the `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` is
>   there - or else refer to this:
>   [ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html](http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.ca/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html)

– [bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) [Nov 7 '12 at 16:38](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214073/help-needed-after-wubi-install#comment265431_214073)